# Когда к методу обязательно нужно обращаться через точку в Scala?

Tags: scala

Когда метод должен вызываться обязательно через точку в Scala? По идее их во многих случаях можно пропускать, однако, следующий пример работает лишь в виде:

```
"Hello".foldLeft(1L)((a, b) => a * b)
```

а вот так уже не компилируется:

```
"Hello" foldLeft(1L)((a, b) => a * b)
```

В чем здесь подвох?

Comment: вот так, кстати, норм `("Hello" foldLeft 1L)((a, b) => a * b)`

Comment: мне кажется компилятор не настолько умен и банально не может определить порядок применения операций, потому что справа после строки может быть функция вовзращающая еще одну функцию и не ясно, применять ее к строке либо продолжить вычисление, передав туда параметры a и b

Answer (score 2):

Точку можно пропускать при вызове функции с одним параметром. В других случаях лучше использовать вызов с точкой.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#arity-1

Лично я считаю вызов без точки надо использовать только в том случае когда функция выглядит как оператор, исключительно для повышения читаемости:

```
//implicit class IntOps(number: Int) {
//    def plus(n: Int) = ???
//}
3 plus 4

// case class User { def and(other: User)= ??? }
alex and john 

val numbers = List(1, 2, 3)
def timesTwo(n: Int) = n * 2
numbers map timesTwo
```